# python sort list of dictionary value with string integer field

Tags: python

Error:

```
TypeError at /api/product/
string indices must be integers
```

code:

```
data = [
        {
        "link": "https://www.kohls.com/product/prd-3751773/laura-geller-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick.jsp?skuid=75792684",
        "price": "21"
        },
        {
        "link": "https://www.skinstore.com/laura-geller-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-chocolate-rasberry/11638314.html?switchcurrency=USD&shippingcountry=US",
        "price": "21.0"
        },
        {
        "link": "https://shop.nordstrom.com/S/4125441?utm_source=rakuten&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=datafeed&utm_content=Women:Makeup:Lip&utm_term=5000548&utm_channel=affiliate_ret_p&sp_source=rakuten&sp_campaign=datafeed",
        "price": 21
        },
        {
        "link": "https://www.macys.com/shop/product/laura-geller-beauty-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-cream?ID=5713197&PartnerID=LINKSHARE&cm_mmc=LINKSHARE-_-4-_-41-_-MP441",
        "price": "21.00",
        "stock": true
        },
        {
        "link": "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Laura-Geller-Iconic-Baked-Sculpting-Lipstick-Chocolate-Raspberry-0-13-oz-3-8-g/597167699",
        "price": "12.88"
        }
]

data = sorted(data, key = lambda i: (float(i['price'])))
```

Here i am trying to sort data by price. But, i am getting error due to string data.
Please have a look how i can solver this problem.

Comment: that sort on the data you provided seems to work fine for me, after I change the `true` to `True`, are you sure the typeerror is in the sort?

Comment: I think OP is misunderstanding the returned value of `data`. It's most likely a json-string that is returned by another source. That would explain the `true` values inside of it.

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**

As mentioned in comments (i.e. Hampus Larsson) your data must be a JSON string.  This explains the error you're getting.  Also, this explains why you have the value true in data.

You can do the following.

**Code**

```
import json

# Data is a string
data = '''[
        {
        "link": "https://www.kohls.com/product/prd-3751773/laura-geller-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick.jsp?skuid=75792684",
        "price": "21"
        },
        {
        "link": "https://www.skinstore.com/laura-geller-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-chocolate-rasberry/11638314.html?switchcurrency=USD&shippingcountry=US",
        "price": "21.0"
        },
        {
        "link": "https://shop.nordstrom.com/S/4125441?utm_source=rakuten&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=datafeed&utm_content=Women:Makeup:Lip&utm_term=5000548&utm_channel=affiliate_ret_p&sp_source=rakuten&sp_campaign=datafeed",
        "price": 21
        },
        {
        "link": "https://www.macys.com/shop/product/laura-geller-beauty-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-cream?ID=5713197&PartnerID=LINKSHARE&cm_mmc=LINKSHARE-_-4-_-41-_-MP441",
        "price": "21.00",
        "stock": true
        },
        {
        "link": "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Laura-Geller-Iconic-Baked-Sculpting-Lipstick-Chocolate-Raspberry-0-13-oz-3-8-g/597167699",
        "price": "12.88"
        }
]'''

# Convert to Python object
data = json.loads(data)  # this also converts true to True while decoding

# now your sort code works
data = sorted(data, key = lambda i: (float(i['price']))) 

# Show results (same as original since already sorted)
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(data)
```

**Output**

```
[{'link': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Laura-Geller-Iconic-Baked-Sculpting-Lipstick-Chocolate-Raspberry-0-13-oz-3-8-g/597167699',
  'price': '12.88'},
 {'link': 'https://www.kohls.com/product/prd-3751773/laura-geller-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick.jsp?skuid=75792684',
  'price': '21'},
 {'link': 'https://www.skinstore.com/laura-geller-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-chocolate-rasberry/11638314.html?switchcurrency=USD&shippingcountry=US',
  'price': '21.0'},
 {'link': 'https://shop.nordstrom.com/S/4125441?utm_source=rakuten&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=datafeed&utm_content=Women:Makeup:Lip&utm_term=5000548&utm_channel=affiliate_ret_p&sp_source=rakuten&sp_campaign=datafeed',
  'price': 21},
 {'link': 'https://www.macys.com/shop/product/laura-geller-beauty-iconic-baked-sculpting-lipstick-cream?ID=5713197&PartnerID=LINKSHARE&cm_mmc=LINKSHARE-_-4-_-41-_-MP441',
  'price': '21.00',
  'stock': True}]
```